# Looking to conduct six different t-tests based on a generated dataset

Tags: r

`lapply(1:5000, function(x) rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=1))` is the function I used to generate the data

`t.test(x, mu=mu0, alt="two.sided", lev=0.95)` is the t-test formula I made

I need to conduct six tests with µ0 = 0, 2, and the three alternatives from alpha=0.05

Comment: Try to post a reproducible example if you can, makes it a lot easier. For example, what is x?

Comment: A piece of the dataset [[1000]]
 [1]  1.78273287  1.80581743 -0.17115945 -0.34005713
 [5]  0.29843558 -0.41456767 -0.17591101  1.09345290
 [9]  1.07316404 -0.02753905  2.13287733 -0.59254887
[13] -1.86189787 -0.80786036 -0.25871874 -0.13442455
[17] -0.36303616 -0.75763297 -0.45287774 -0.17325517

Comment: You need to clarify what the “tests” are testing. The default for t.test is for two independent samples. You have 5000 samples. Are you supposed to be taking pairs of samples for testing?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Are you looking for something like this?

```
x <- sapply(1:50, function(x) rnorm(n=20, mean=0, sd=1))
my_mu <- c(0.1,0.2,0.3,0.4,0.6)


 map(my_mu, function(a) {
  t.test(x, mu= a, alt="two.sided", lev=0.95)
})
```

x and y from the t.test require a numeric vector of values, sapply has the ability to return numeric vector of values, lapply returns a list so t.test can't take it.

Comment: I appreciate the suggestion. I think map is a non-base r function. I can only use base r function

Comment: lapply works the same, replace map with lapply

Comment: I used the lapply function and was able to generate the data sets. The issue I'm having is with running the t-tests off of the dataset that the lapply function generated

Comment: Ok, so let me get this clear. The lapply function you gave created a 1000 item list of 20 normally distributed values. Do you want each index of the list have a t-test ran on it?

Comment: It is actually 5000 but essentially yes.  Each of the 5000 datasets have to have six tests ran on it with mu=0, 2 and the three alternatives. Using alpha=0.05

Comment: `data <- lapply(my_mu, function(c) {
  lapply(x, function(a, my) {
  t.test(a, mu= c, alt="two.sided", lev=0.95)
  })
})` nested lapply should give you 6 list of 5000 tests